# Minifying and Hosting Google tag manager JavaScript files locally

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, minify

*Before I start I should mention that I know about [Hosting the Google JavaScript file locally](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en) is not recommended by Google. But since the Caching time is so low on these files I want to have it locally with much more cache time. I also automatically get the last version when the real file is changed.*

I'm trying to fetch ga.js file by cron everyday like this and host it locally:

```
$ana = file_get_contents('https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js');
if ($ana!==false){
   file_put_contents('ANA_LOCAL_PATH',$ana);
   $tag = file_get_contents('https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js');
   if ($tag!==false){
      $tag = str_replace('https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ANA_LOCAL_URL',$tag);
      file_put_contents('GTAG_LOCAL_PATH',$tag);
   }
}
```

I'm also getting `analytics.js` file and replacing Google URL with local `analytics.js` file.

But I want it to be future proof. Google using this URL:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxxx-x
```

I'm using this:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js
```

I have more than 10 tag manager ID and I only get the JavaScript file one time without ID.

Another thing is that Google header file is starting with this:

```
// Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
(function(){

var data = {
"resource": {
  "version":"1",
  "macros":[],
  "tags":[],
  "predicates":[],
  "rules":[]
},
"runtime":[
[],[]
]
```

- This file has multiple new lines (not only on header) which is not minified properly.
- I found Google does not minified the script well. for example, `case "url_no_fragment"` has space after case. It can be `case"url_no_fragment"`. You can find lots of `switch case` with white space in the file.

**The Question**

1. Is Downloading method has problem (now or future), just because I don't get it with Google tag manager ID?
2. Can I minify Google files with my own method and remove some flaws that I mentioned?
3. I know this part is not programming related and I think I'm getting NO for this. but just for the sake of minification. Am I allowed to remove that copyright comment to have the best minify file?